# Settings API saved values not getting shown in the dropdownbox

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, settings-api

I am trying to save a value into the options using Settings API. The thing is getting saved, but no matter what I do, it always resets the dropdown box. So the saved values are not shown in the drop down box.

I am using var_dump() to show the contents of the Options and it is showing the rpeviously saved values without any problem. Can someone please help me? Here is the screenshot: 
[image]
Here is the code:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'twmm_init');
function twmm_init() {
  register_setting('twmm_options_group', 'twmm_options', 'twmm_options_validation');
  add_settings_section('twmm_setting_section', 'TWMM Settings', 'twmm_section_callback', 'twmm-settings.php');
  add_settings_field('twmm_on_off', 'Enable or disable the maintenance mode here:', 'twmm_status', 'twmm-settings.php', 'twmm_setting_section');
  add_settings_field('twmm_permission_lvl', 'Minimum permission level needed to access the site:', 'twmm_permission', 'twmm-settings.php', 'twmm_setting_section');
}
function twmm_status() {
  $options = get_option('twmm_options');//check if maintenance mdoe is enabled or disabled
  echo "<select id='twmm_on_off' name='twmm_options[twmm_on_off]'>";
    echo "<option value='Enable'" . selected( $options['twmm_on_off'], 'enabled') . ">Enable</option>";
    echo "<option value='Disable'" . selected( $options['twmm_on_off'], 'disabled') . ">Disable</option>";
  echo "</select>";
}
function twmm_permission() { //drop down box for user roles
  $options = get_option('twmm_options');
  echo "<select id='twmm_permission_lvl' name='twmm_options[twmm_permission_lvl]'>";
    echo "<option vaule='admin'". selected( $options['twmm_permission_lvl'], 'admin')."> Admin </option>";
    echo "<option vaule='editor'". selected( $options['twmm_permission_lvl'], 'editor')."> Editor </option>";
    echo "<option vaule='author'". selected( $options['twmm_permission_lvl'], 'author')."> Author </option>";
    echo "<option vaule='contributor'". selected( $options['twmm_permission_lvl'], 'contributor')."> Contributor </option>";
    echo "<option vaule='subscriber'". selected( $options['twmm_permission_lvl'], 'subscriber')."> Subscriber </option>";
  echo '</select>';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misspelling `value` to `vaule`:

```
echo "<option vaule='editor'". selected( $options['twmm_permission_lvl'], 'editor')."> Editor </option>";
```